# Unauthorised Perl Scripts

Tags: linux, perl, webserver, centos

One of my servers just had the memory exhausted by a load of Perl scripts, we use plesk and they seem to have appeared under the `/var/www/vhosts/domainexample.com/cgi-bin/` directory, I managed to stop all of the processes and delete the scripts but I have absolutely no idea how they would've got there.

Can someone point me in the right direction in order to prevent further attacks?

Comment: Guessing this belongs on security.se. Still, have you checked who owns the file and when it was created? It's either a user of your system that just took some old/insecure Perl scripts from the web, or a hacker misusing your application to upload cgi scripts into your cgi-bin.

Answer (score 0):

- Who should have access to your webserver machine?
- Does this include the owner/operator of domainexample.com?
- Do you expect the owner to be placing cgis on your server?
- Does domainexample.com need to run cgis?
- does domainexample.com need to run perl?

You might want to start researching here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/security_tips.html